# Matching words from two title and calculate %

Tags: excel, vba

I was trying to automate an Excel file which has title in both A and B columns and I have to search each word from A within B and calculate the % by using the "no of words matched/total no of words (in column A)" formula.

I'm using the below code, however its not giving me the accurate %. Can anyone help me out please.

```css
Sub percentage()

Dim a() As String
Dim b() As String
Dim aRng As Range
Dim cel As Range
Dim i As Integer, t As Integer, clm As Integer

Set aRng = Range(Range("A1"), Range("A65536").End(xlDown))

For Each cel In aRng
    a = Split(cel, " ")
    b = Split(cel.Offset(, 1), " ")
    d = 0
    clm = 2
    C = UBound(a)
If cel.Value <> "" Then
    For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
    
            For t = LBound(b) To UBound(b)
                If UCase(a(i)) = UCase(b(t)) Then
                    clm = 2
                 Do While True
                    If UCase(cel.Offset(, clm)) = UCase(a(i)) Then
                    Exit Do
                    End If
                        If cel.Offset(, clm) = "" Then
                            'cel.Offset(, clm) = a(i)
                            Exit Do
                        End If
                        clm = clm + 1
                    Loop
                    d = d + 1
                End If
            
            Next
            
    Next

cel.Offset(0, 2).Value = (d / c)
End If
Next

End sub
```

[image: Skkakkar Result]

Comment: Please go through my analysis on sample data. Your program is reading one word less from column A but correct no of words from Column B except for initial iteration stage. I have uploaded my analysis and you can refer test2509a.xlsm file<https://www.dropbox.com/s/di7rwkihdsyzpqa/test2509a.xlsm?dl=0> It may help you in improving the program.

Comment: Please remove `'` from the line `If cel.Offset(, clm) = "" Then
                            'cel.Offset(, clm) = a(i)
                            Exit Do` This will give you correct no. of words in Column B. Now Look into Problem in Column A it is reading one word less except header line.

Comment: Hi thanks for the sample code and update. I'm still getting the same result Please take a look at the image in "Result" column your sample file's result and expected result (with 100% accurate) and after removing the codes you mentioned above I'm getting **Runtime error "1004"**.

Comment: Removing the comment is giving problem. I am still analyzing it. Please restore the comment tick for the time being. Another suggestion is If we make ` c = UBound(a) ` to ` c = UBound(a) + 1` Column A word count comes ok except for header. Could be due to 0 base vs 1 based.

Comment: Yes that's working skkakkar thanks again :). Is there any other simple way to automate?

Comment: Please see my reworked sample file. It is giving correct results except that rounding off is required. <https://www.dropbox.com/s/di7rwkihdsyzpqa/test2509a.xlsm?dl=0> Regarding simple way I shall think it over. May I put my answer mentioning only changes as the sample file is already uploaded. You may accept the solution if it is working for you.

Comment: Thanks for the sample file skkakkar :). I'm waiting for your simple method and curious to learn new way :)

Comment: I am posting an improved version of program which is better approach in my view point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make the changes. `c = UBound(a) + 1 'change here`
Multiply by 100 and use rounding function `cel.Offset(0, 2).Value = (d / c)`
Your program code should work correctly.

******EDIT On 28-09-2015 *********
Another version of program considered a better approach by me for the OP's question.

**** EDIT 29-09-2015 ******
Retesting of program for different combination of words in the string revealed that this update of program is not giving consistent results in all type of situations, Hence Update of program on 28-09-2015 stands withdrawn.

```
Sub percentage_rev()
   Dim a() As String, b() As String
   Dim aRng As Range, cel As Range
   Dim i As Integer, t As Integer
   Set aRng = Range(Range("A1"), Range("A5").End(xlDown))
   For Each cel In aRng

       a = Split(Trim(cel), " ")
       b = Split(Trim(cel.Offset(, 1)), " ")
       d = 0
       c = UBound(a) + 1 'change here

    If cel.Value <> "" Then
      If InStr(cel, cel.Offset(, 1)) Then
          d = UBound(b) + 1
    Else
         For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
             For t = LBound(b) To UBound(b)
                 If UCase(a(i)) = UCase(b(t)) Then
                     d = d + 1
                 End If
           Next
        Next
     End If
    End If
   cel.Offset(0, 2).Value = (d / c) * 100 'multiply by 100 for percentage
   Next
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: In our codes I'm getting incorrect percentage for which if either of the title has repeated words (Duplicate words) in title. Any idea to tackle this issue? Sorry i couldn't able to upload the image due to system issues.

Comment: @Linga I shall check it little later tonight and infrom you my findings.

Comment: @Linga  I have rechecked on a new set of sample data. It is showing correct results with the updated program. Reviewed file is uploaded to drop box.<https://www.dropbox.com/s/2tf3v0iwmvxetx5/test2509a_revw2909.xlsm?dl=0>

Comment: your correct in your test file its running perfectly. Please take a look at the image example under your updated code, that's what I'm trying to explain it to you. Hope now you got it ?

Comment: This problem can occur if the previous contents of file formatting are present. I suggest try out code on a new worksheet with new set of data and untick  the ~debug.print~ in the code to get the values of count integers in the immediate window. This shall enable you to follow the program code execution and check the count values with the actual words physically there in the sheet.  I hope you will get the correct results.

Comment: @sakkakkar i tried it in a worksheet but still I'm getting the same result as shown in the image :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90920/discussion-between-skkakkar-and-linga).